# MVC3 passing messages from one controller to another view and/or controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, message

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app. that has an import from Excel function.  This function is performed in the Import method of the Rate controller.  It is viewed in the Rate/Import view.  When importing, some rows are successful, some are not.  I am gathering the errors into a string[] array.  The import is considered successful if one or more rows is successfully imported, therefore the app navigates back to the Proposal Edit view.  I want to pass the informational errors back to the Proposal Edit view for display.   Any ides how to do this?

Comment: By "the app navigates back to the Proposal Edit" do you mean you're doing a redirect after the form is submitted? If so, the only place you're going to be able to store information is in a database (passing an ID over to the other controller to go lookup the strings), in a session or in a cookie. The ViewBag/ViewData lifecycle ends with the life of the request. A redirect creates a new "Request" from the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways.

**TempData**

This is available in your controller.  TempData persists across a single redirect.

```
public ActionResult Process()
{
    // ... Process your rows, get array of errors back ...

    TempData["errors"] = errors;
    return RedirectToAction("Edit");
}

public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var errors = (IEnumerable<string>)TempData["errors"];  // Get the errors back.
    return View(errors);  // Pass into the view
}
```

**ModelState**

You could add these errors directly to the ModelState and then redisplay the edit form.  It doesn't persist across a redirect.

```
public ActionResult Process()
{
    // ... Process your rows, get array of errors back ...

    for(var i = 0; i < errors.Length; i++)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("row" + i, errors[i]);
    }

    // Can't redirect here - ModelState doesn't persist.
    return View("Edit");
}
```

Then, in your edit view, just display the validation summary:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("The following row errors occured:");
```

This will render this html.  The class is the default one set by MVC.

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors">
    <span>The following row errors occured:</span>
    <ul>
        <li>...Error 1...</li>
        ... Other errors ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @leniency....thanks a lot.  Good stuff!  Question on the ModelState....how does the ModelState display the errors?  Does there need to be more code in the Edit view?  Thanks

Comment: @MikeTWebb Yes, the last line, `@Html.ValidationSummary("The following row errors occured:");` is what displays any errors in the ModelState.     Updated my answer with what that renders out.